# Implementation of Graph C++ (nodes are characters)

Tags: c++, graph, stl, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have two classes, one is Graph.h and Vertex.h (Directed Graph)

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H                              #ifndef GRAPH_H
#define VERTEX_H                              #define GRAPH_H


#include <iostream>                          #include "vertex.h"
#include <vector>                            using namespace std;

using namespace std;                         class Graph {

class Vertex {                               private:

private:                                     vector<Vertex> vertices;
vector<char> edges;                          
char label;

public:                                     public:

Vertex(char);                               void addEdge(char,char);
void addEdge(char);                         int vertexCount();
char getLabel();                            bool vertexExists( char );
const vector<char> getEdges();              bool pathExists( char, char );

};                                          };

#endif /* vertex_h */                       #endif /* graph_h */
```

I already solved it using bfs, but i think there would be more efficient solution using  dfs.
I inserted some nodes for test,

```
graph = new Graph();

graph->addEdge( 'P', 'R' );
graph->addEdge( 'P', 'W' );
graph->addEdge( 'Q', 'X' );
graph->addEdge( 'R', 'X' );
graph->addEdge( 'S', 'T' );
graph->addEdge( 'T', 'W' );
graph->addEdge( 'W', 'S' );
graph->addEdge( 'W', 'Y' );
graph->addEdge( 'Y', 'R' );
graph->addEdge( 'R', 'Z' );
```

I implementaion if sketched will be looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J95Aj.png)

My question is how would I perform a DFS/BFS to see if there is a path exists between P->T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether breadth-first or depth-first is more efficient would depend entirely on the topology of your graph. The breadth-first approach will find the shortest route to a node (useful in navigation, but not in `pathExists`), but don't confuse that with finding the route in shortest number of moves.

In both cases you maintain a record of what nodes have been visited, typically a bitmap if the graph is large (`std::vector<bool>` is usually suitable).

And, in both cases you maintain a "list" of what vertices to visit next. Initially the list contains only the starting point, but as you visit each vertex you add the connected vertices to the list, if not already visited.

In the case of a breadth-first search the vertex list is operated as a queue, in which new vertices are added to the tail of the list.

In the case of a depth-first search the vertex list is operated as a stack, in which new vertices are added to the head of the list. It's possible to dispense with an explicit list, and use the call stack, via function recursion, to hold the list implicitly.

The search is over when you find the target vertex, or when the stack/queue is empty (in which case there is no route).